# how can I get the total number of notes without retrieving them all

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In order to go through all notes of a user I first want to know the total number available. The only way I found so far is to get them all by setting the limit to a high enough value - but this is pretty slow since all note objects will be fetched including their content. There must be a more effective way since the normal public `https://www.facebook.com/<user>?sk=notes` page displays the total at the bottom line very quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get only number of `notes` without fetching the details for all of 'em.

You can however speed the query by limiting fields retrieved by adding `fields` argument to `notes` connection URL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/notes?fields=id&access_token=...
```

This will only return `ids` of notes without all the rest of details (which should be faster that retrieval of all notes data).